# C++ / C: Trim the first word of each line of a text file

Tags: c++, c, string

I am looking for a C / C++ or even C# code that will trim the first word of a each line in a text file

e.g. file.txt

```
test C:\Windows\System32\cacl.exe
download C:\Program Files\MS\
```

So I will be left with:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cacl.exe
C:\Program Files\MS\
```

I have the current code, but it doesnt seem to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char s[2048];
    while (fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin))
    {
        char *pos = strpbrk(s, "|\r\n");
        if (pos != 0)
            fputs(pos+1, stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm I missing something?  There is no space in your second argument to `strpbrk`.

Comment: Well at least you're flexible in accepting wildly different solutions in totally different languages. But what has [windows] to do with anything?

Comment: C or C++? You have to choose. Looking at your example, that's definitely C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string tmp;
   while ( !cin.eof() )
   {
      cin >> tmp;
      getline(cin, tmp);
      cout << tmp << endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: I get a compile error: "strimmer.cpp `String' undeclared (first use this function)"

Comment: sorry string with lower case s

Comment: and also "strimmer.cpp `end' undeclared (first use this function) "

Comment: @downvoters? What's the problem?? Because of 2 characters being wrong? That someone with minimal knowledge of C++ whould find in a sec?

Answer (score 3):

C#:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("...");
var removedFirstWords = from line in lines
                        select line.SubString(line.IndexOf(" ")+1);
```

(Didn't check it. Might contain errors)

Comment: This is the way to go. If you need to get each string independently, then rather than using the LINQ, you could just `foreach` `lines` which is a string array.

Comment: Indeed. When the file containing the lines is huge this way will have a huge memory impact. So reading an parsing line by line from the file might be better then.

Answer (score 2):

In C#:

```
var fileContent = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\1.txt");
var result = Regex.Replace(fileContent, @"^\w*\s+(.*)$", "$1", RegexOptions.Multiline);
File.WriteAllText(@"c:\2.txt", result);
```

Answer (score 1):

C#:-

```
string line = "test C:\Windows\System32\cacl.exe";

string output = line.substring(line.IndexOf(" "));
```

Comment: Hi, the lines in the text file are unknown, hence can't be predefined as a string

Comment: @James you said text file - text is string data.

Comment: @Chuck - I think he meant he couldn't initialise a string variable in the code. It would have to be read from the file contents. Erno's answer looks like the one.